# Termux: pkg update shows "Waiting for cache lock" and it doesn't seem to stop

Tags: android, installation, package, apt, termux

I just downloaded Termux and used the 'pkg upgrade' command, then it showed me showed some options:

Y or () | Upgrade... (I can'tremember what)

N or () | Keep current version

D | Show differences

()

()

I then pressed D to see the differences,  and a long manual-like text appeared.
But I didn't know how to exit and press either Y or N. I tried some things but no luck. So I closed Termux and exit from the notifications and tried again.
However, this time I couldn't get 'pkg upgrade' to work. Instead this was shown:

[image: Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock]

Running Processes:

[image: Running Processes]

Now, the second count goes above 5000s...

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for `apt` to finish the task before starting another `apt` task.

Comment: But what is it supposed to be doing? The upgrade didn't even let me write Y or N anymore

Comment: @KaiVinter You have multiple ```apt``` processes running, try killing them then try again. Do ```kill <PID>```.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your PId is 16216 , just
Kill 16216